# Ошибка запуска приложения при отладке

Tags: java, android

Не отображается название процесса в logcat, процесс устройства эмулятора отображается. Использую Android Studio 3.0.1. Собственно вот ошибка при отладке:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah/com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah/com.android.tencent.zdevs.bah.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Comment: а само приложение при такой ошибке запускается?

Comment: Да ,запускается

Comment: Попробуйте отключить InstantRun в настройках студии и ещё попробуйте clean сделать.